# The view shifts after the keyboard is finished loading, how to I get the view to shift at the same time

Tags: swift, animation, keyboard

When I call my keyboard it will slide up into place, then the rest of the view will slide up to make room for it. Similarly when I dismiss the keyboard, the keyboard will slide out, then the rest of the view will slide down. Is it possible to have the keyboard and the view to slide at the same time?

Here is the code I currently have

```
// MARK: Animated Keyboard
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    // check to see if a keyboard exists
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        print("Show")

        // Check to see if the information for the size of the keyboard exists
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo
            else {return}

        // get the size of the keyboard
        guard let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue
            else {return}

        // get the duration of the keyboard transition
        let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double

        // get the type and speed of the keyboard transition
        let curve = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt

        // move the frame by the size of the keyboard
        let keyboardFrame = keyboardSize.cgRectValue
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: -0.2, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardFrame.height
            }
        }, completion: nil)


    }
}
```

This is not causing any errors, it compiles and runs without issue. It just looks bad.

Comment: I like your attempt at time travel with a negative delay. :)

Comment: Try `animate` instead of `animateKeyframes`

Comment: Just to verify, did you connect this `keyboardWillShow` method with the `WillShow` notification and not the `DidShow` notification?

Comment: i changed it to UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: but it still does the same thing

Comment: the notification center bits are in the view did load section, if thats what you mean. Should they be somewhere else?

Comment: No, I mean verify which notification you registered for. Make sure it's the keyboard *will show* and not the keyboard *did show* notification.

Comment: @rmaddy this was the issue. in my view did load I had "NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)" When I should have had the second part say WillShow as well. if you want to type this up as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description is sounds like you have actually registered for `keyboardDidShowNotification` instead of `keyboardWillShowNotification`.

Make sure you have registered for the correct notification.

You should also use the `UIView.animate` method and not `UIView.animateKeyframes`. This of course also means you need to replace `UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions` with `UIView.AnimationOptions`.

Lastly, don't attempt to use a negative delay. UIKit has a lot of power but time travel isn't one of them.

Comment: I really didn't think the negative delay would work. I tried it on a lark and forgot to take it out before posting the question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just having a little fun with it. :)